# Error removing instances of successfully completed cloud dataflow jobs

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I see the following error when the job is nearing completion:

```
2015-01-22T11:25:59.785Z: (6a513162c75566fe): Starting worker pool teardown.
2015-01-22T11:25:59.793Z: (6a513162c7556a9a): Stopping worker pool asynchronously...
2015-01-22T11:35:59.867Z: (564988ad48e37d5d): Executing failure step failure1
2015-01-22T11:35:59.870Z: (564988ad48e37857): Workflow failed. Causes: (6a513162c7556e36): Step teardown_resource_global_gce_worker_pool69: Resource worker_pool_resource failed to shut down
2015-01-22T11:36:00.121Z: (564988ad48e37bc8): Stopping the input generators.
2015-01-22T11:36:00.153Z: (e9be8a1b4a36d7a3): Cleaning up.
2015-01-22T11:36:00.169Z: (e9be8a1b4a36db46): Tearing down pending resources...
Jan 22, 2015 1:36:01 PM com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner run
INFO: Job finished with status FAILED
```

After that, the worker instances are not removed and I have to kill them manually.

Is it a known bug?

Thanks,
G

Comment: Fixed now.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the trouble.  This is a known issue.  I'll update this thread when we address it, and thank you for your patience.

**Update**

This issue has been fixed in the service.